# Update statement does not update database records

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

SQL update statement does not update records in database when running the application, but It updates if I run the same Update statement in SQL  Server Management studio

```
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("XXX").ToString())


        Dim command As New SqlCommand("Update EmployeeMedicalTest SET [Date tested] = @DateTested, [Next Due date] = @NextDueDate, ECG = @ECG,  Lungfunction = @Lungfunction,   [Hearing Test] = @HearingTest,  [Eye Test] = @EyeTest,  [Other Problems] = @OtherProblems, Notes = @Notes WHERE Code = @code", conn)

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTested", txtDateTested.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextDueDate", txtNextDueDate.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ECG", txtECG.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lungfunction", txtLungFunction.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HearingTest", txtHearingTest.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EyeTest", txtEyeTest.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherProblems", txtOtherProblems.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", txtClockNo.Text)

        conn.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblSaveNotify.Visible = True


        conn.Close()
```

Comment: Make sure you are accessing correct database connection string

Comment: Are you sure your connection is pointing to the database you are checking for updates? Also, just a tip regarding creating a connection. You should rather wrap the connection in a using statement (I forget the vb syntax for that just now) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement. This will ensure that the connection is closed and disposed even if an exception occurs. You won't have to explicitly close the connection either.

Comment: Please show your connectionstring. Are you using the shortcut _|DataDirectory|_? What tools do you use to check if your data has been updated? Is this tool using the correct database? What is the return value of ExecuteNonQuery? Is this value 0 or >0?

Comment: Hi guys, I do not believe that the problem is my connection string as I have used the exact same connection string to perform an insert and it executed successfully.I will definitely try using the Using statement as suggested thanks . ```Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LumotechPortal.My.MySettings.GuHR_Data").ToString())```

Comment: Then please capture the result of ExecuteNonQuery (the number of rows changed by your query) There are two possibilities: If it is zero then no record matches the WHERE condition, it is >0 then you are updating but not the database expected.

Comment: I have done that now and a zero was returned @Steve

Comment: So the culprit is the WHERE statement. No match. Side note. AddWithValue could be very buggy with conversion between strings (TextBox.Text is a string) and the actual type expected by the database. I would use Add passing the paramenter type and converting the string to the datatype expected in the database column. And this is more true for dates fields (Next Due Date etc)

Comment: Thanks so much @Steve for your help, I will look at that and at least I know now where my problem is.

Comment: Hi guys I am still having a problem, because the textbox [txtClockNo.Text] that is pointing to the parameter @code does contain a value in it, but somehow the WHERE clause does not use it or compares to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tevin . . . Do not use `AddWithValue()`.  Be explicit about the data types.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have used this now and still nothing has happened command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClockNo.Text.

Comment: are you by any chance running this inside a try catch and burying the exception? Check the immediate window so see if you have any thing in there.

Comment: It is fine guys thanks I have managed to find the solution. I was clearing the Text box from which my WHERE statement was reading from and so there was a blank value to compare to. Thanks for your help. @CharlesMay. Gordon Linoff , Steve , Andrew , Jaydip Jadhav.